# Parse JS SDK : Manually mark attribute as Dirty

Tags: parse-javascript-sdk

I am experiencing very occasional instances where the parse js sdk does not detect that an Array attribute has changed ... and is therefore not including it in the payload on a `save()`.

I can see there is `Parse.Object.dirty(key)` which will return if the field is dirty.

But is there a way to manually mark an attribute as dirty ?

Comment: same story in android

Comment: ok, not sure if this had something to do at all with your problem, but this it what happened to me: 1.- update object with object.put 2.- wait this to be completed 3.- go to dashboard and click on refresh 4.-double click in my array column->"damn! the array its not updated,why!!??" 5.- click out the column-> this for some reason launches an update in the database. And there it was my problem!! 1.- refresh was not actually refreshing 2.- that update launched was over writing with the old and wrong value. So all I had to do was close the web, repeat steps, open again the web, and vualá... ¬.¬

Comment: worth checking this out : https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/542